# What is ExternalRDDScan in the DAG?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs, internals

What is the meaning of ExternalRDDScan in the DAG?

The whole internet doesn't have an explanation for it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ExistingRDD.scala#L58), `ExternalRDDScan` is a representation of converting existing RDD of arbitrary objects to a dataset of `InternalRow`s, i.e. creating a `DataFrame`. Let's verify that our understanding is correct:

```scala
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> rdd.toDF().explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#1]
```

Answer (score 4):

ExternalRDD is a logical representation of DataFrame/Dataset (not in all cases though) in the query execution plan i.e. in DAG created by the spark.

ExternalRDD(s) are created

1. when you create a DataFrame from RDD (*viz. using createDataFrame(), toDF()* )
2. when you create a DataSet from RDD (*viz. using createDataSet(), toDS()* )

At runtime, when the ExternalRDD is to be loaded into the memory, a scan operation is done which is represented by ExternalRDDScan (internally the scan strategy is resolved to ExternalRDDScanExec). Look at the example below:

```
scala> val sampleRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))
sampleRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> sampleRDD.toDF.queryExecution
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution =
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
value: int
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#1]

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- Scan[obj#1]
```

> You can see that in the query execution plan, the DataFrame object is
>   represented by ExternalRDD and the physical plan contains a ***scan
>   operation which is resolved to ExternalRDDScan (ExternalRDDScanExec)***
>   during its execution.

The same holds true for a spark Dataset as well.

```
scala> val sampleRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))
sampleRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> sampleRDD.toDS.queryExecution.logical
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#23]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#22]

scala> spark.createDataset(sampleRDD).queryExecution.logical
res18: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#39]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#38]
```

The above examples were run in spark version 2.4.2

Reference: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-LogicalPlan-ExternalRDD.html